# Loading filepicker widgets fails

Tags: filepicker, filepicker.io

I'm having a weird issue. I'm using the filepicker 'pick' widget to upload a logo. When the page is first rendered, the widget is shown. However, if I navigate away from the page and visit it again, the widget is not rendered. I have to explicitly clear the cache to see it again. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Is your app using something like Pjax to load the pages?
Filepicker initializes the widgets on page load. If the page is loaded via something like
pjax, then the widgets will need to be re-initialized everytime you navigate to that page.

eg:
filepicker.constructWidget(document.getElementById(idOfElementToBeConvertedToWidget))

I've had to do this on an app that I am building that uses Pjax.